# Debugging Javascript with babel in VS code skips lines

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-debugging

I create a directory `test` and `npm init` in it. I write a simple code to `index.js`:

```
'use strict';
let i = 3*4;
console.log("HELLO TEST");
console.log("HELLO TEST");
```

With this in `package.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/index.js",
      "stopOnEntry": false,
      "args": [],
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "preLaunchTask": null,
      "runtimeExecutable": null,
      "runtimeArgs": [
        "--nolazy"
      ],
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "development"
      },
      "externalConsole": false,
      "sourceMaps": false,
      "outDir": null
    }
  ]
}
```

Now, I put a breakpoint at line two and run the code. Everything works as expected, I can step through the code line by line and see the values update (in this case, the value `i` updates) and write to the console after

Now I install `npm install --save-dev babel-cli` and modify the launch.json: `"runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/.bin/babel-node",`

[Now the debug line isn't aligned, it starts off here, and `i` isn't defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j0dR.png)

The problem worsens when I add more lines:

[`i` is still not defined!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JV1gx.png)

A few days ago, I didn't have problems like this. I didn't change node versions. I might have changed VS code versions. Currently, I installed the latest version (1.3.1) and I get this problem. I also tried to revert to 1.2.1 and still have this problem.

I don't understand how I can get this to work again. It was perfect before! It's a big pain not to be able to debug correctly.